# Powershell Script to replace accented letters in multiple files not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace ALL accented letters and some strings in multiple files located in one folder. The strings replacement is working but not the accented letters

I've multiple files located in `"C:\\FilePath"`

I've created a Batch file with the following code:

```
@echo off
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\Users\User\Desktop\IFCParser.ps1
pause
```

And `IFCParser.ps1` contains all the following lines, one after the other:

```
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern 'IFCBuilding') {(Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace 'IFCBuilding', 'IFCBuildingElementProxy'}) | Set-Content $_  }}
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern 'IFCAnotherWord') {(Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace 'IFCAnotherWord', 'IFCBuildingElementProxy'}) | Set-Content $_  }}
```

The above code DOES the job when I run the bat file, but I can't get the following part to work:

```
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'á' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'á', 'a'}) | Set-Content $_  }}
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'é' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'é', 'e'}) | Set-Content $_  }} 
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'í' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'í', 'i'}) | Set-Content $_  }} 
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'ó' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'ó', 'o'}) | Set-Content $_  }} 
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'ú' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'ú', 'u'}) | Set-Content $_  }} 
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'Á' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'Á', 'A'}) | Set-Content $_  }} 
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'É' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'É', 'E'}) | Set-Content $_  }} 
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'Í' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'Í', 'I'}) | Set-Content $_  }} 
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'Ó' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'Ó', 'O'}) | Set-Content $_  }} 
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\FilePath\*.* -recurse | ForEach {If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'Ú' -AllMatches) {(Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach {$_ -creplace 'Ú', 'U'}) | Set-Content $_  }}
```

I'm testing this on a file like this:

```
áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñáéíóúÁ

ÉÍÓÚÑñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñá

éíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñáéíó

úÁÉÍÓÚÑñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÑñ
```

And it stays the same, no accents removed.
I think that I've something wrong with the encoding, I've run this with the parameter just in the first GetContent, only on the second one, and with no -Encoding at all.

By the way, I'm sure that there are more effective ways of doing this, but I'm just starting with this here and not finding one that works.

Comment: I've removed your [[tag:batch-file]] tag. The method you are using to run the PowerShell script is irrelevant to your reported problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for replacing the contents of the files in your folder, you should be able to do that using just one `Get-ChildItem` call.

Put this helper function on top of your script; it is used for replacing all the accented letters in the files:

```
function Replace-Diacritics {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string] $Text
    )
    ($Text.Normalize( [Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD ).ToCharArray() |
     Where-Object {[Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($_) -ne
                   [Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark }) -join ''
}
```

Now the rest of the code simplified:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\FilePath\*.*' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw -Encoding UTF8 | Replace-Diacritics
    $content -replace '\b(IFCBuilding|IFCAnotherWord)\b', 'IFCBuildingElementProxy' | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Using your example file, the new content after calling `Replace-Diacritics``will be:

```
aeiouAEIOUNnaeiouA

EIOUNnaeiouAEIOUNna

eiouAEIOUNnaeiouAEIOUNnaeio

uAEIOUNnaeiouAEIOUNn
```

<sup>Operator `-replace` uses regex. The pattern `'\b(IFCBuilding|IFCAnotherWord)\b'` means to find he words 'IFCBuilding' OR 'IFCAnotherWord' as whole words (`\b` is a Word Boundary) and replace these with 'IFCBuildingElementProxy'.

If you also need this to be case-sensitive, use `-creplace` instead of `-replace`</sup>

---

For very large files, Get-Content may not be the cmdlet you'll want to use as it reads the file in memory as a whole.

To handle those large files using a combination of a [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader) and a [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter) would be much more memory efficient (at the cost of more disk read/write actions).
Note that you cannot read a file and write to the same file simultaniously, so the code below will create a new name for the updated file by appending `_New` to the BaseName.

Again start with this helper function on top

```
function Replace-Diacritics {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string] $Text
    )
    ($Text.Normalize( [Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD ).ToCharArray() |
     Where-Object {[Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($_) -ne
                   [Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark }) -join ''
}

 Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\FilePath\*.*' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # create a StreamReader to read the file line-by-line
    $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.FullName, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
    # older PowerShell versions use:
    # $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($_.FullName, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)

    # create a full path and filename for the updated output file
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath ('{0}_New{1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension)
    # create a StreamWriter object to write the lines to the new output file
    # The StreamWriter class by default writes files with UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM)
    $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($outFile)

    # loop through the lines of the file
    while ($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line)) {
            $line = ($line | Replace-Diacritics) -replace '\b(IFCBuilding|IFCAnotherWord)\b', 'IFCBuildingElementProxy'
        }
        $writer.WriteLine($line)
    }
    # clean up for next file
    $writer.Flush()
    $writer.Dispose()
    $reader.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, that was a GREAT help ! I appreciate the time you took.
The script works as expected. I'm still having some troubles with the performance processing BIG text files (like 500Mb big), but I'm yet in the testing process. Thanks again

Comment: @MatBaren Thanks for the nice feedback. Please see my edit, where I have added code for very large files as alternative. Also, being quite new to the platform, may I point you to the [tour], where amongst other interesting stuff about SO, you can read how to mark a question 'done' if someone solves your problem with his/her answer.

Answer (score 0):

Running a single line of code on a single file like this works as expected:

```
Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\temp\testdata.txt | ForEach-Object {
    If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String 'á' -AllMatches) {
        (Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 | ForEach-Object { $_ -creplace 'á', 'a' }) | Set-Content $_  }
}
```

Given this, your code must be failing in the file recursion or in the execution process.

Run the script in an editor before trying to run as a batch and try adding error trapping. You can also add some logging to track down what's happening when running as batch:

```
Start-Transcript -Path 'c:\temp\outputlog.txt'
Try {
    Get-ChildItem  -Path C:\temp\testdata.txt -recurse -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Processing $_"
        If (Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8 -ErrorAction Stop | Select-String 'á' -AllMatches) {
            Write-Host "Found match for á, replacing...."
            (Get-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object { $_ -creplace 'á', 'a' }) | Set-Content $_ -ErrorAction Stop }
    }
}
Catch {
    $_
    Stop-Transcript
}
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Thank's for the input! I really do need to implement some logging,. 
I've already added a progress bar, to track a bit, but I know I still have to work on the log